# How do I get the WinForm Designer to totally ignore a property on a custom control?

Tags: .net, winforms, properties, attributes

*This must be a FAQ, but I can’t find a duplicate question!*

There are lot of different attributes that control what the WinForm Designer does with properties on a custom control, I am never clear on the one I should use in this case.

I am looking for:

- Designer does not show property in grid
- Designer does not read value of property
- Designer does not set property to default value
- E.g. Designer behaves as if the property **was not there**.
- Designer does not complain if it has already done one of the above before the attributes were added (hard!)

---

Background.

The code that is giving me the problem is:

```
this.eventListControl.FilterSets = 
   ((SystList<FilterSet>)(resources.GetObject("eventListControl.FilterSets")));
```

The FilterSets property should never have been touched by the winforms designer; it is now not Serializable and MsDev falls over every time a form that used the eventListControl is changed!

Comment: Additionally, ILMerge doesn't properly rewrite this, so if `FilterSets` was in a DLL that got merged in, this line of code will throw.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think you can use `[Browsable (false)]` and `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]`

The second attribute prevents the property from appearing in `InitializeComponent`

Comment: thanks, that stops the desinger added it to InitializeComponents in new forms, however the designer can still not read the resouce files for forms that allready have the control, so I have to edit the resouce files by hand.

Comment: Not working for .NET6 VS2022. Won't ignore the property. Designer throws an error.