# Visual Studio is automatically changing one of my properties to null

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

How can I tell it to back off and leave the property alone?

Here's the property:

```
/// <summary>
/// Collection of SednaTreeViewItems used to populate the SednaTreeView.
/// </summary>
public IEnumerable<SednaTreeViewItem> TreeNodes
{
    get { return treeNodes; }
    set 
    {
        ultraTree.Nodes.Clear();
        treeNodes = value;
        foreach (var item in treeNodes)
        {
            UltraTreeNode node = new UltraTreeNode(item.ValueMember, item.DisplayMember);
            ultraTree.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I'm in the designer and change another property it seems to detect this one as a Property and set it to null. Is there a decorator I can use to make it ignore the property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is the [`DesignerSerializationVisibility` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.aspx), which prevents the designer from serializing the value of the property (i.e., adding junk to your `Designer.cs` file).

It looks like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

/// <summary>
/// Collection of SednaTreeViewItems used to populate the SednaTreeView.
/// </summary>
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public IEnumerable<SednaTreeViewItem> TreeNodes
{
    get { return treeNodes; }
    set 
    {
        ultraTree.Nodes.Clear();
        treeNodes = value;
        foreach (var item in treeNodes)
        {
            UltraTreeNode node = new UltraTreeNode(item.ValueMember, item.DisplayMember);
            ultraTree.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly and no longer changes my property to null.

Comment: @Sergio: Cool. I notice another answerer recommended using the `Browsable` attribute. You can do that, too, if the property shouldn't show up in the Properties Window at design time. But you don't have to use them together. They work completely independently of one another.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an attribute to make it not "Browsable" in the designer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx

Browsable didn't quite work, but there is another question that offers another attribute.

[How do I get the WinForm Designer to totally ignore a property on a custom control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598733/how-do-i-get-the-winform-designer-to-totally-ignore-a-property-on-a-custom-contro)

Comment: Using that decorator correctly removed that property from the Properties window, yet the value is still being set to null in .Designer.cs - Any suggestions?