# WinForms custom control insertion with designer generates error in call to __identifier in InitializeComponent

Tags: .net, winforms, custom-controls

Using Windows Forms, C++/CLI, I create custom controls in a project, build it, and then they are available in the designer for the other projects in the solution. Neat

However, I've been getting a frequent error in the designer, that I don't know very well how to systematically reproduce nor to solve: sometimes when I open the designer view of a form, I get a C++ Code Dom parse error "Member __identifier not found in class [class of a custom control]". 
It get's "solved" (patched up) by opening the code, going to the line in question and commenting. The line is always one of the defaults added by the designer inside InitializeComponent. For example

//this->tb_long_m->__identifier(value) = 1.7976931348623157E+308;

I'd appreciate some guidance in solving this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think __identifier is made public instead of private.
Or you can add the attribute `[Browsable(false)]` on your identifier.

Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598733/how-do-i-get-the-winform-designer-to-totally-ignore-a-property-on-a-custom-contr)

Hope this helps.