# Replacing 3rd party Windows Forms UI controls in a large codebase

Tags: winforms, user-interface, refactoring

Me and my colleagues are investigating how to replace 3rd party WinForms controlls by our new UI controls in our large legacy codebase. Practically we would like to replace the 3rd party controlls in the inheritance chain. The 3rd party controlls are used dozens of places by subclassing the 3rd party UI controlls. We d like to perform this change as safety as possible, with minimal code change all over the solution. Do you have any experience how to start? Obviously the inheritance means strong coupling here, so i d like to find the less painful solution here.

Is the "branch by abstraction" concept applicable here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty subjective decision based on your team's understanding of the code base as well as workflow.  The bright side is that you've already subclassed all the controls, so you've already done the tedious work of being able to provide whatever properties the code is looking for to compile.

Given that this is WinForms, this should be much more straightforward, since the control sizes and locations are set on the `Control` level.  You need to worry about mapping properties/methods that exist in the old vendor's controls to your new controls and not as much about form layout.  This might be straightforward for some controls and more complex for others (i.e. grids).

The biggest roadblock IMO is going to be handling the current design-time serialized logic in `InitializeComponent`.  If you've created a property to map from old -> new, you're going to have to be careful that when the designer re-serializes everything after you open the form and modify something, you might not want to serialize both the old property and the new.  As an example:

**Old Vendor**

```
this.myOldComponent.Data = this.dataSource;
```

**New Vendor**

```
this.myNewComponent.DataSource = this.dataSource;
```

In this case, you may consider creating a new property called `Data` on your subclassed new component so that the old code works without changing anything.  Let's say you open the form in the designed and move the grid a few pixels, causing the designer to serialize the data.  You might now have:

```
this.myNewComponent.Data = this.dataSource;
this.myNewComponent.DataSource = this.dataSource;
```

You can prevent serialization with attributes (good discussion on it in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598733/how-do-i-get-the-winform-designer-to-totally-ignore-a-property-on-a-custom-contr), but this is just an example of something you might hit.

I don't think there's really a pattern here to follow, unless you mean on the source control level, in which case I would say to absolutely create a new `branch` apart from your regular development one; who knows what kinds of roadblocks you may hit and you'd want to shelve your work for a bit.

Ultimately, you may decide that it's just best to suck it up and rip out the old components and put in the new, but as mentioned this is very subjective.  It's situations like this that make me really love **WPF** and the **MVVM** model, since you could entirely rip out the UI and keep the business logic intact.